# How do I resolve my dependencies for testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, integration-testing, ioc-container

My controllers have dependencies that I'm resolving with dependency injection using Castle Windsor.

This works great and even allows me to substitute some dependencies with "mock" dependencies so that I can test my controllers.

However, suppose I have the following:

```
Public Class AccountController
    Inherits Controller

    Public Property SecurityService As ISecurityService

    Public Sub New(securityService As ISecurityService)
        Me.SecurityService = securityService
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DefaultSecurityService
    Implements ISecurityService

    Public Property SomeDependency As ISomeClass

End Class
```

In this case my `AccountController` depends on having an `ISecurityService` which then depends on another class of some sort. My situation is more complex with more abstraction. I have absolutely no access to directly inject anything to the `SecurityService`.

This made me think that my DI container could do it for me. I want to have Castle Windsor recognise when I'm running a test (such as an integration test) and substitute any services any "mock" services that it finds. This means I could define a mock `ISomeClass` called `MockSomeClass` and Castle Windsor would automatically inject that one instead of the regular class.

How might this be achieved? The only piece of information I could find on this topic was [Auto-mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/) by [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann). But it's complex and I'm not sure if it's even related to what I need.

(VB.NET and C# are acceptable in code examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given that you can inject an interface into the controller means that defaultsecutiryservice's dependencies are moot.

simply use a mocking tool of your choice like MOQ, RhinoMocks etc and then give accountcontroller one of those mocks.

In MOQ, I would do the following:

```
 var service = new Mock<ISecurityService>();
 service.setup(s= > s.SomeCall(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new List<OfSomething>());

 var controller = new AccountController(service.Object);


 controller.DoSomething(5); // call on service as check the result here

 service.Verify(m => m.SomeCall(It.Is<int>(i => i == 5)), Times.Once());
```

Using a mocking tool like this, you don't need to worry about dependencies of the dependency, as it is not the dependency you are testing, merely the interaction between the two.

When you come to test DefaultSecurityService, that is when you need to worry about it's dependencies.

HTH